# Website Data Crawler, posting data and traversal

Tags: traversal, web-crawler, posting

Although there have been quite some posts on these topic, my question is little bit specific.
I need to parse few website and once done, I need to send some data to it. For example, say website A offers me a search tab, I need to programatically feed data to it. The resulting page might differ based on target site's updates.
I want to code such a crawler. So which tools/language would be best to realize this?
I am already well-versed in java and C, so anything based on these would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/). It's completely free and Windows, Linux, Mac are supported.

- It is very simple to install.
- It is very simple to execute using
  command line.
- Community is pretty big and solving straight-forward
  problems is trivial.
- It uses JavaScript as the scripting language so you'll be fine, I guess, with your Java background.
- You'll have to get familiar with DOM structure. Well, you cannot write a crawler without knowing it (even in case you select completely visual solution).

Everything depends on how frequently the crawler should be executed: PhantomJs is great for long-term jobs. Use something else, visual, like [iMacros](http://www.iopus.com/iMacros/) in case you're looking for one-time solution. It can be used inside Mozilla as an extension (free of charge) and there's a standalone version that costs money.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Andrey!.. I will try phantomjs for now.Looks interesting !! :)